# asp.net mvc pass parameters between view and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am a novice in asp.net and i want create simple database application.
I need pass parameters between view and controller to retrieve data from database.
i need only this data which title is "something". I create simple left menu which contains search settings.
This is my view page.

```
@model IEnumerable<TwojaBiblioteka.Models.Ksiazka>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<div class="jumbotron">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h2>Szukaj</h2>

            <div class="textboxes">
                <input type="text" name="Tytul" class="form-control" id="Tytul" placeholder="Tytuł..." />
                <input type="text" name="txtAutor" class="form-control" id="txtAutor" placeholder="Autor..." />
                <input type="text" name="txtISBN" class="form-control" id="txtISBN" placeholder="ISBN..." />
            </div>              
            <center>
           @Ajax.ActionLink("Szukaj", "SzukajKsiazki", new AjaxOptions()
      {
          HttpMethod="GET",
          UpdateTargetId= "divKsiazki",
          InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace
      })
            </center>
        </div>
        <div id="divKsiazki"class="col-md-10 ">  
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is view for display data from database:

```
@model IEnumerable<TwojaBiblioteka.Models.Ksiazka>
<table class="table" style="border:1px solid black;">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tytul)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Autor)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ISBN)
    </th>       
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tytul)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Autor)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ISBN)
    </td>      
</tr>
}
</table>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public PartialViewResult SzukajKsiazki()
    {
    string tytul="something";

        var ksiazkilist = db.Ksiazka.Where(x => x.Tytul == tytul).ToList();
        return PartialView("_ListaKsiazek",wypozyczone);
    }
```

So how i can pass data from my textboxes to controller to display only those records which contains textbox text?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action should accept a parameter. In Asp.Net MVC, it is normal for this to be the model:

```
public PartialViewResult SzukajKsiazki(IEnumerable<TwojaBiblioteka.Models.Ksiazka> model)
```

Your view should have all of the editor elements from the model enclosed in a form and you need a submit button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SzukajKsiazki", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)
{
<table class="table" style="border:1px solid black;">
<tr>
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tytul)
</th>
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Autor)
</th>
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ISBN)
</th>       
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tytul)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Autor)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ISBN)
</td>      
</tr>
}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
}
```